# Double curly braces (Jinja2) not working in Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am new to web development and I came across this very annoying issue.

Here is my app.py code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

all_posts = [
    {
        'Title': 'Post 1.',
        'Content': 'Content in Post 1.'
    },
    {
        'Title': 'Post 2.',
        'Content': 'Content in Post 2.'
    }
]

@app.route('/posts')
def posts():
    return render_template('posts.html', posts=all_posts)
```

The all_posts variable gets sent to posts.html.

Here is posts.html code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head%} 
<title>Posts</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body%} 
<h1>All Posts</h1>

    {% for post in posts %}

        <h2> {{post.title}} </h2>
        <p> {{post.content}} </p>

    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

But when I run /posts in the browser, nothing inside the double curly braces gets displayed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: move `all_posts` array inside your `def posts():` function block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates variables are `case-sensitive`. Try the following instead:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head%} 
<title>Posts</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body%} 
<h1>All Posts</h1>

    {% for post in posts %}

        <h2> {{post.Title}} </h2>
        <p> {{post.Content}} </p>

    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```